# Infinite while loop in Python 3.6

Tags: python, loops, infinite

I have some values say `amt1, amt2` and `val1 = .75, val2 = 1.25`. I would like to do something like this:

Say `amt1` is 1000 and I multiply by `val1` 1000 * .75 = 750 and then assign that amount to `amt2`, so `amt2 = amt1 * val1`.

I then multiply `amt2` by `val2`, so 750 * 1.25 = 937.

If the product of `amt2 * val2` is less than `amt1`, then do the entire calculation again until `val2` has a value which results in the sum being more than `amt1`.

I would also like it if it does equal more to then do the entire thing again but with inverted values kind of like this. I'm really not sure how to implement this or even really how to ask the question properly.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Sun Jul 23 00:57:28 2017

@author: Anwar Goulouh
"""

def infiniteloop():
#   TRADE1
#   define an amount to trade first myAmt1, define what base currency is 
#   and currency to trade to nzd and usd, define exchange rates for both,
#   once i have completed the second trade I would like to do trade 1 again
#   only the myAmt1 will be the value in myResult2
myAmt1 = int(10000)
print ("My Amount 1 = $",myAmt1)
myVar1 = "nzd"
myVar2 = "usd"
#   Iwould like these following two values to be either a webrequest from 
#   google or random decimals for myVar1ExRate value will always be 1 an the 
#   second will be something between 0.701 and 0.909 so need to figure out 
#   how to generate the random number also for now i will use hardcoded 
#   values
myVar1ExRate = int(1.00)
myVar2ExRate = float(0.7565)
print ("ex rates", myVar1,myVar2,"NZD ExRate =", myVar1ExRate,"USD ExRate 
=",myVar2ExRate,)
#   do first trade
print ("do first trade $",myAmt1, "* USD Ex Rate",myVar2ExRate,)
myAmt2 = int(myAmt1*myVar2ExRate)
print ("My Amount 2 =$",myAmt2)
#   TRADE2
#   I then attempt to trade the full amount of myAmt2 back from USD to NZD 
#   and make a profit to do this the 
#   the exchange rate of the NZD must be above a certain amount otherwise
#   it will result in a loss i do not know how to correctly code the if 
#   statement for this but will make an attempt the idea is that it runs 
#   infinitely.
#   So...
#   I then switch the values of myVar1 and my Var2 as follows and put them 
#   to new vars so I can use them again i also need to define the previous 
#   amount of MyAmt1
myVar1Prev = (myVar1)
myVar2Prev = (myVar2)
myAmt1Prev = (myAmt1)
#   I now perform the switch
myVar1 = (myVar2Prev)
myVar2 = (myVar1Prev)
print ("New currencies", myVar1, myVar2)
#   add the new exchange rates
myNewExRate1 = int(1)
myNewExRate2 = float(1.2523)
print ("New ex rates", myVar1,myVar2,"USD ExRate =", myNewExRate1,"NZD 
ExRate =",myNewExRate2,)
#   now i need to do an if statement and if it fails then try again until 
#   MyNewExRate2 has a value which equals a profit
if  myAmt1Prev == (myAmt1Prev < myAmt2 * myNewExRate2):
    myNewAmt2 = int(myAmt1Prev < myAmt2 * myNewExRate2)
    print ("the Amount is less than$", myAmt1Prev)
else
    myAmt1Prev == (myAmt1Prev > myAmt2 * myNewExRate2):
    myNewAmt2 = int(myAmt1Prev > myAmt2 * myNewExRate2)
    print ("you made a profit$", myAmt1Prev)      
#   once this is all done say if myNewExrate had been 1.4565 and i had 
#   successfully made a profit I want to then put the new amount I had made 
#   in the else statement to myAmt1 then do the if statement again to see if 
#   i would make a profit trading back to USD and so on forever
#   I should be able to get this to run infinitely but am unsure how to code 
#   it effeciently and correctly  I dont know?????

infiniteloop()
```

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you are asking in terms of the statements to be evaluated.  Could you update the question to include the line by line equations e.g. amt1=100, val1=-0.5; amt1 = amt1 * val1 etc....

Comment: From your description you don't seem to modify `amt1`, `val1`, `amt2`, `val2`. So `amt2 * val2 < amt1` is either `True` or `False` for the whole procedure, no matter how often you do the described calculation (which was not at all clear by the way, maybe you can show the different steps, using pseudo-code).

Comment: I've tried to make the question more readable, but I'm still not really sure what you want to achieve. Please try to edit your code example, so that it's more [complete](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And make sure that it's formatted correctly (there have to be 4 extra spaces before each line (just select your code in the submission window and press Ctrl-K to indent it)).

Comment: I have attempted to be a bit clearer on what im trying to do hopefully this helps there are some errors in my code im not sure how to fix any help would be fantastic also things i dont know how to do like get data from google and put it to the exchange rates or do a loop of the code

Comment: I'll take a closer look at the code tomorrow. If you don't know how to use `for` and `while` loops, you have to read a tutorial first (for the google stuff as well).

Comment: i would i simply have extremely limited internet and to be honest i find tutorials not always relevant to how i am working this way with you awesome fellows teaching me is relevant fast and i meet new people ! :~)

Comment: Yes, you can learn a lot on SO, but it's really not a site where you should learn the basics or ask for tutorials (that would be off-topic). Are you actually just asking how to use loops in this question? Then maybe it would be better to delete the question. Some interesting online beginner books that I can recommend are "Program Arcade Games with Python and Pygame" and "Automate the boring Stuff".

Comment: thanks i took your previous advice and managed to find some good basics tuts i will check your other suggestions, i did manage to get a while loop and most other aspect i wanted working and posted another question could you please take alook a that code and see if you can help you have been very helpful so far and its a bit more advance i think also do you know anything about how to pull data off websites say google currency rates?? that is advanced for you

Comment: Write @skrx to send me a notification. There's a chapter about ["Web Scraping"](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter11/) in Automate the boring Stuff.